# SQL Query needs to return rows even when results are null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I've been replacing a set of CLR stored procedures with straight SQL but I've been stuck on this one report.

The system makes entries into a stats table when an event occurs. If a particular event doesn't occur, there is no entry in the HourlyStats table.

```
Table HourlyStats
    UserID    TimeStamp     EventID  Duration
      1       (datetime)       5        36
      2       (datetime)       1       259
      1       (datetime)       2        72
      3       (datetime)       5        36
```

Let's say there are 5 different eventID's in a table Categories

```
 Table Categories
       EventID   Description
           1        Break
           2        Supervision
           3        Lunch
           4        Outbound
           5        Inbound
```

There is also a table of Users

```
Users
UserID  Name
  1     Tom
  2     Mary
  3     George
  4     Carly
```

and the output has to look like:

```
UserID    Description     Sum(TimeSec)
 Tom          Break           Null
 Tom         Supervision       72
 Tom         Lunch            Null
 Tom         Outbound         Null
 Tom         Inbound           36
 Mary        Break            259
```

I've tried a variety of joins but don't get the results I'm looking for.

It may be that I can't do this directly via a single query. My next approach is to construct a temp table structured like the Output table but with NULL values for the SUM column and then update the table with results.

I've tried many variations. Here is where I started

```
SELECT HourlyStats.UserID, Categories.Description, SUM(HourlyStats.Duration) AS Expr1
FROM Categories FULL OUTER JOIN
HourlyStats ON Categories.EventID = HourlyStats.EventID
Group by UserID, Description
Order by UserID
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is very do-able with a outer join.  It would help if you showed your query, no?

Comment: Show your attempt. It would be very helpful to as to help you.

Comment: I am just too lazy to create all the tables and data, so I will give you a hint: `(Categories CROSS JOIN USERS) LEFT JOIN HourlyStats`. Probably require minor tweaks to get correct data in required order. EDIT: You may want to look at other solutions if list of `Users` is too big.

Comment: Thanks, the CROSS JOIN does the trick. The list of users and categories is relatively small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT u.Name, c.[Description], hs.Duration
FROM Users u
CROSS JOIN Categories c
LEFT OUTER JOIN HourlyStats hs
ON u.UserID = hs.UserID
AND c.EventID = hs.EventID
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `CROSS JOIN` to get every possible combination of `USERS` and `EVENTS` and than `LEFT` join to `HourlyStats` code will be like this

```
;WITH   base
          AS (
               SELECT u.UserID
                   ,u.name
                   ,c.EventId
                   ,c.Description
                FROM Categories AS c
                CROSS JOIN Users AS u
             )
    SELECT b.name
           ,b.Description
           ,SUM(hs.Duration) OVER ( PARTITION BY hs.UserId, hs.EventID ) AS SumTime
        FROM Base AS b
        LEFT JOIN hourlyStats AS hs
            ON b.UserID = hs.UserId
               AND b.EventId = hs.EventID
        ORDER BY 1 DESC
       ,2 ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cross join the users and categories then left join in the hourly stats.  This should do it.

```
select u.Name, c.Description, sum(hs.Duration)
from Users u
cross join Categories c
left join HourlyStats hs on hs.UserId = u.UserId and hs.EventId = c.EventId
group by u.Name, c.Description
order by u.Name, c.Description
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fef9/2)